# When saving a CSV in Excel 2016, can you change which delimiter it uses without changing your regional settings?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

If you Google how to save a CSV with a delimiter other than a comma, you often get results like these:

[Example 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2016-excel/excel-2016-saving-csv-file-using-comma/5a963cf5-d272-4a0b-b706-fa7760041596?auth=1)

[Example 2](http://optimalbi.com/blog/2015/07/16/how-to-export-an-excel-file-to-pipe-delimited-file-rather-than-comma-delimited-file/)

[Example 3](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/)

I've used this method before and it works, but it screws up other things on my computer that rely on these regional settings. Is there something in Excel 2016 (or other versions) that lets me choose the delimiter without changing the regional settings?